Active ventilation fan in encapsulated crawl space
I need some advice on where to place an active ventilation fan in my encapsulated crawl space. I have a dehumidifier positioned as shown in the diagram. The crawl space is encapsulated but lacks ventilation. I've watched a YouTube video that mentions the EPA recommends having an active ventilation fan to get rid of soil gas.
The fan I bought suggests placing it around the corners of the foundation. Where should I place the active ventilation fan if my goal is to maximize airflow and create a circular motion of air throughout the crawl space?
I like the blue corner the most because it is opposite to the dehumidifier, which will help pull the air across the longest possible path within the crawl space.


If your crawlspace is fully encapsulated, then why is there soil gas getting into it to begin with...?  (Normally, you encapsulate a crawlspace because you want to put it inside your house's envelope)

I'm no expert, but it seems that soil gas can still escape from the ground and diffuse into the crawl space. Since this area is sealed, there is no outlet for the musty odors. Consequently, these smells can migrate to your first floor, causing it to smell like the crawl space. Additionally, this situation could increase the risk of radon exposure in some areas (mine's moderately okay).
